# Creating a safe dev environment

Tags: php, wordpress, git, github

We are a small team developing a Wordpress site. Till now we have been editing the same files online, which inevitably led to mistakes. We thought to use Git / Github to stop stepping on each others tows and manage source code efficiently. However I can not run the site locally on XAMPP as I am getting numerous PHP errors. What would you recommend in this case?
Maybe creating another folder on the server with identical content just for testing? Is it possible then to run Git on the server?

Comment: Well what PHP errors are they?

Comment: I tried editing some config files to adapt to the local environment (for the required statements), and then I get lots of syntax errors. I fix one, another ten appear.

Comment: yes running git on a server is fine, But you wouldnt benefit from stepping on each others toes. Local is best option

Comment: Nice reading: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/119/12615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I operate in a team of devs and this is what we do.

1. Locally each set up our own wordpress install under a seperate vhost and locally modified dns. Get just plain jane wordpress running perfectly.
2. Create a dev testing site on a live server on the internet (often prefix the real url with dev-www.mysite.com)
3. Create a GIT repository, and have it auto push-deploy to the dev testing site (we create the folder structure in GIT from wp-content down, and only have custom themes/plugins)
4. Configure GIT to MANUALLY push changes to the production server (for going live)
5. On all systems we install the wp-migrate-db-pro plugin. Locally devs only PULL from the shared dev site to their local (which means planning what/when/where you create content).
6. Copy around the /uploads folder, incase there are a bunch of images/media uploaded.

This works when some of us run Windows/IIS/WordPress, Mac/Apache/WordPress, Linux/Apache/WordPress

Comment: so I need to the the local version to work...fff...it just seems impossible with all those errors. I do not understand this part "under a seperate vhost and locally modified dns", could you elaborate? or direct me to some resources to study?

Comment: With apache, you can look up setting up multiple vhosts. This allows multiple sites to run locally...each with a different dns name. I try to use local-www.mysite.com, local-www.othersite.com etc. To get these dns entries to work, you have to modify your local HOSTS file.

Comment: When I say get local version to work....first try to get the basic install of wordpress to work. Not the site that you are trying to get working.

Answer (score 0):

As a general idea a deployment process could go like this:

- developers push their git changes to the server 'staging' area
- either manually or using git's post processing, changes are pushed is needed to a virtual Wordpress web host that acts as test or 'staging' server. This can be password- or geolocation-protected
- once it's tested properly, then the code can be moved to production web host files, this can be accomplish with a simple script that goes like: stop web server - backup files - nuke files - move files from staging - start web server